# Active Directory not keeping RDP alive in log so FW can allow internet

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, fortinet

I have a Fortinet firewall that looks at my AD to recognize my domain users to grant access to the internet and for the most part it works perfectly except for when users remote into computers from another computer (not a TS).

We have a computer in our conference room and a user will go in there and remote into their computer at their desk to run some special software or something.  The issue is that when the user launches the RDP session, it no longer reports to AD that the user is still logged into their computer and times them out on the firewall and once this happens, the computer they are remoted into loses its internet privilege.

Is there anything I can setup in AD to recognize an RDP session as a user still being logged in so my firewall can get that message and continue allowing it to the internet?

I have 2 Server 2008 R2 DC's and a Server 2016 DC and only 1 domain.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that when the user launches the RDP session, it no longer
>   reports to AD that the user is still logged into their computer

A computer is never "reporting" to the domain that a user "is still logged on", this is not an AD thing. FSSO is polling the state from the delegated kerberos node (which is fetched from AD, thats right).

I would change the authentication time for FSSO. Connect to CLI and:

```
config user fsso-polling
edit <ID>
set logon-history <24>     (0-48, default is 8. Try 24 for 24hr logon history.)
next
end
```

Comment: I will give it a shot

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.  Fortinet support told me I dont have FSSO polling from the FGT

Comment: Then you are using ... ? NTLM? NTLM/FSSO? NTLM/Kerberos? LDAP-Auth?

Comment: I believe its LDAP-Auth

Comment: So they seem to think it is the security layer that my RDP sessions are using and it should be set to Native rather than the default negotiate

Comment: So ... the question about Active Directory has been answered? This is a Fortnet thing.